# How does celery task rate_limit and expires works

Tags: python, django, celery, celery-task

I am working with Celery in a Python application, and I have a specific requirement for one of my tasks. I've defined a Celery task as follows:

```
@app.task(rate_limit="1/m")  # The task should execute once every minute
def task_test():
    print("Hello")
```

I invoke this task in my code like this:

```
from celery import Celery
from flask import Response
from http import HTTPStatus

celery = Celery(__name__)
celery.config_from_object('celeryconfig')

def execute_task():
    task_test.apply_async(expires=5)  # I would like the task to be revoked if it hasn't executed within 5 seconds
    return Response(status=HTTPStatus.OK)
```

The issue I've encountered is that after triggering the execution of the first task and waiting for one minute, I attempted to trigger the second task. However, the second task failed to execute.

The second task should be execued